# Good way to chain or combine multiple "patchers"?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is a very common pattern in React where we "patch" a component and it will receive custom properties:

```
export default gimmeMahProps(someRandomSettings)(MyComponent);
```

Examples:

```
// Redux
connect(stateMapper, dispatchMapper)(MyComponent);

// Material UI
withStyles(myStyles)(MyComponent);
```

This can get quite messy when we have more and more of these functions:

```
// messy nested function calls with only two of those patchers
export default connect(stateMapper, dispatchMapper)(withStyles(myStyles)(MyComponent));
```

This is what I am doing now to avoid having a pyramid of nested function calls:

```
export default [
    connect(stateMapper, dispatchMapper),
    withStyles(myStyles)
].reduce((comp, patcher) => patcher(comp), MyComponent);  // kind of a hack
```

More readable, but what I am looking for is a simpler way to chain or combine them together. Maybe I'm missing something, but does React offer any API to achieve this?

Comment: See https://github.com/acdlite/recompose

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, its name is **function composition**, one of the basic "patterns" in functional programming (or in any language, where functions are the first-class citizens, which is true for JavaScript also).

You can take a look at [`compose` from `redux`](https://redux.js.org/api-reference/compose)

Or, IMO it is better to, pick Ramda's [`compose`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#compose) (right-to-left application) or [`pipe`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#pipe) (left-to-right application). Difference in short:

```
compose(fn1, fn2)(x) === fn1(fn2(x))
pipe(fn1, fn2) === fn2(fn1(x))
```

Your example of ugly code can be written this way

```
const enhance = pipe(
  withStyles(myStyles),
  connect(stateMapper, dispatchMapper),
)

export default enhance(MyComponent)
```

Also, note that there is an upcoming language feature called *[pipeline operator](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-pipeline-operator)*.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The `compose` function is quite handy and fits my case here nicely. It would be awesome if the pipeline operator proposal got accepted but for now the `compose` function will do.

Answer (score 1):

What about using JavaScript decorators?

```
@connect(stateMapper, dispatchMapper)
@withStyles(myStyles)
export default class App extends Component {
    ...
```

There’s a fantastic library called [Core Decorators](https://www.npmjs.com/package/core-decorators) that provides some very useful common decorators that are ready to use right now. These generally allow for very useful common functionality (e.g. timing of method calls, deprecation warnings, ensuring that a value is read-only) but utilizing the much cleaner decorator syntax.

Comment: Be warned: decorators are still a stage-2 proposal and have already had major changes from their earlier versions (but _boy_ are they useful).

Comment: I would wait until decorators are finalized before using them, but thanks for the suggestion.